# iOS Push notification using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apn

I am working in a project where I need to show notifications fired by Firebase. Everything works fine with the `send and receive flow`. But I need to customise the notification before showing it, i.e., when the app is in background. Because the message I receive from our server it's already `Base64 encoded`. And therefore the notification displays a long string that my petrify the users.
**Is there any delegate or something which I can use to modify the received data before** `presenting` **it when the**  *`app is in background`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way in iOS to do that. Please refer to this answer for more details [How to change how a remote notification is presented before presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621956/how-to-change-how-a-remote-notification-is-presented-before-presentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these following in your project to handle any data.

Works only for iOS 10.2 or greater

UNNotificationServiceExtension

UNNotificationContentExtension

Go through this link - https://medium.com/@prianka.kariat/ios-10-notifications-with-attachments-and-much-more-169a7405ddaf

As i have limited time please let me know if you need more explanation on this.

Debugging is also a tricky part in this First you go through this then try to debug by  GO to  DEBUG -> Attach to process by pid  and paste your extension name you added.

Comment: Our concern is to handle the **Data** and **Notification** before the app enters foreground. Because the data (as in Chat) we receive is base64 encoded. We need to decode it before showing.