# iOS Swift How to change incoming payload notification alert message displayed in banner?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, payload

I have a payload coming in from a web service and part of what I receive is this:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert = "Message from Web service";
sound = default;
}
```

And when I receive a notification when app is in the background, it will show the notification banner with the "Message from Web service" string. How do I change this string? I'm checking and I don't see any functions being called when app is receiving notifications in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: change what the web service sends.

Comment: What if I want to handle this without web service change?

Comment: I dont think you can 'intercept' and change the contents of a push notification before it is shown. it is received and shown and your app is notified about it. thats it.

Comment: other option is to send a silent notification from the web service instead and present your own local one with the modifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621956/how-to-change-how-a-remote-notification-is-presented-before-presentation/49622282#49622282